# datagridview editingcontrolshowing checkboxcell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to change the backcolor of the edited cell when I have a checkboxcolumn in my datagridview.

For textboxcolumns the backcolor is easy to set but for some reason I don't catch this event on the checkboxcolumn when it goes into edit mode.

Is there something different I need to do to handle this scenario? I am guessing comboboxcolumns are similarly different?

Based on thetimmer's suggested answer I added the following code to the cellbeginedit event of my datagridview but it has no effect on the coloring.

```
If e.ColumnIndex = datagridview1.Columns("checkboxcolumn").Index Then
    Dim c As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = datagridview1.CurrentCell
    c.Style.BackColor = Color.Red
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This works once you've left the cell

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellBeginEdit
    Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub
```

Comment: I implemented this but it's not working. Sample code added to original post

Comment: when it worked for me was after I checked or unchecked the checkbox then tabbed out of the field.  Did you see any change when you tried that?

Comment: I didn't try that scenario but I need visual representation that the cell is in edit mode regardless of whether they change the checkstate. I appreciate your efforts though.